# Apache Jackrabbit - where is rep.home set ?

Tags: jackrabbit

Playing with jackrabbit.  Got the tutorials loaded on a Linux VM.

Trying to understand the configuration files and I see (in repository.xml):

```
<FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
    <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository"/>
</FileSystem>
```

Easy enough, the variable is the parent.  What I am trying to figure out is where is rep.home defined ? I find it being used a lot but cannot figure out where it is set. I have a bunch of repository directories:

```
/home/andy/Desktop/netbeans/jackrabbit/jackrabbit/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-core/src/test/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-core/target/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-core/target/simple_repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-core/target/repository/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-core/target/repository-2/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-core/target/repository-factory-test/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-core/target/repository-lock-test/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-core/target/simple_repository/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-jca/target/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-jca/target/repository/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-jcr-commons/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/commons/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-jcr-commons/target/classes/org/apache/jackrabbit/commons/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-jcr-rmi/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/rmi/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-jcr-rmi/target/classes/org/apache/jackrabbit/rmi/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-jcr-server/target/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-jcr-server/target/repository/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-spi2jcr/target/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-spi2jcr/target/repository/repository
/opt/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-standalone/jackrabbit/repository
```

I have looked for config files to set that variable as well as checked the java parameters.   What am I missing ?

Tips/pointers/RTFMs appreciated

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [JackRabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/jackrabbit-configuration.html) Project, look into web.xml file. You will see servlet `RepositoryStartup`.

For this servlet, parameter `bootstrap-config` has the mentioned file in which repository home mentioned (probably `bootstrap.properties`)

Comment: OK still confused.  There is a variable repository.home=jackrabbit/repository
Makes sense.  But the repository.xml references rep.home and not repository.home.  Is that a shortcut ?

Comment: yup. it is JackRabbit Configuration variables. See http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/jackrabbit-configuration.html